# fgetc loop returning wrong result

Tags: c

I'm using fgetc and a character-counting method to loop through a file of characters and return them in reverse order. Two unexpected things happen when I try and do so. When I paste a second iteration of the loop below the first it returns a very different, wacky result. As well, the first loop returns the correct result except for an additional character at the start.

For example, if the file contains the string 'Hello' the first iteration will return `5olleH` and the second `HeHeHeHeHeHeHeHeHeHeHeHeHeHe`. The correct result would be `olleH` for both loops.

Here is the code:

```
FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );    
count = count_characters(file);
int originalCount = count;

while(count){

ch = fgetc(file);
printf("%c", ch);
fseek(file, -2L, 1);   // shifts the pointer to the previous character
count--;

}

count = originalCount;

while(count){

ch = fgetc(file);
printf("%c", ch);
fseek(file, -2L, 1);   // shifts the pointer to the previous character
count--;

}
```

Comment: You need to set the file position (using `fseek`) correctly.

Comment: Why are you using 1 instead of `SEEK_CUR`?, even if they are the same, is hard to read.

Comment: @KeineLust Because that's what the [code OP copied from](http://www.studytonight.com/c/program-to-reverse-content-of-file.php) used. OP, try to understand what the code does instead of copying code and expecting others to fix it.

Comment: Correct ;) They return the same thing in this case.

Comment: you need to seek to the end of the file before the second loop. Your extra garbage is because you read the file then step backwards. Your first loop begins with the file at EOF, you need to position on the last char

Comment: @interjay, ahhh, ok, what an ugly code :(

Comment: `fseek(file, -2L, 1);` is UB ; "For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the ftell function ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what state things are left in by count_characters().  Also at the end of the first loop, you should be at the beginning of the file (actually before it).  In the second loop, you keep moving backward.

I'd set a buffer size and read the buffers from the file.  For small files, read the whole thing (your algorithm should account for files smaller than the buffer).  That would seem easier to me.